# Update Standard field with a value from a custom field

Tags: apex, workflow, opportunity, custom-field, standard-objects

I have a field in the Opportunity section called **Amount** that was getting an Install charge from the standard products in the opportunity section. The problem is that now I've added a function to add a new product that is not in a price book, so for example if a we put 2 Standard products with install value of 100 and 1 non standard product with the value of 200 the custom field called **Total_Value__c** charge will be 400 but the **Amount** field will only show the values from a standard product (200).

[image]

The Amount field is the one that pops up on forecasts so I need it to show the total value of both non-standard and standard products. 

Does anyone know how to update that field automatically and possible change all the historic field to be updated ?

Answer (score 1):

A way to solve your issue is to create a workflow on the Opportunity Object that populates your field on updates/insert events. Afterwards you can use the dataloader to upload a list with all the opportunity ids so that the workflow would update all your historical data as well.

Comment: I only did workflow formulas to send emails when a field is changed.  How would I go about updating the fields ?

Comment: Create new rule - > Select the Object ( opportunity in your case) -> add the rule criteria - > save and next -> add workflow action of new field update , then you select the field you want to update and set it to the the value you want to update it with

Answer (score 0):

The Amount standard field on Opportunity is a bit tricky. Once you've added Products to your Opportunity, you will no longer be able to edit it.

A solution would be to create your own Roll-up Summary field to calculate the your own custom amount field. This will also calculate retro-actively, so you have 2 birds with one stone!

Comment: Do you mean a roll up summary on a forecast tab ?  My Total_Value__c (Total Installation cost)  is a roll up from the standard and non standard installation charges.

Comment: @Greg Apologies, I didn't answer that part of your question. Since Winter '15, forecasting on custom fields is GA. See the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_sales_custom_splits_forecasts.htm) for more info.

Comment: @Greg also bear in mind that you cannot use formula fields in the forecasting tab, as far as I'm concerned